# Need help to identify the longest string separated by space

Tags: c

I need to make a code that identifies the longest string of characters that a separated by space. If there are characters of same length, write them both.

Ex: 
Input = Java flow car tree
Output = Java flow tree

Her is the code i wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char cuv[100], big[100];
    int i;
    printf("Scrieti cuvintele\n");
    gets(cuv);
    cuv[0] = big[0];
    for(i = 0; cuv[i] = '/0'; i++){
        if(cuv[i] > big[i]){
            big[i] = cuv[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%s", big);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is i dont know very well how char works. So i have little clue on what to do. I ask of you on how to use the char set to be able to count strings in a specific way.

Comment: use `fgets()` and  `strtok()` and `strlen()`

Comment: `cuv[i]='/0'` is wrong on at least two levels.

Comment: In `cuv[0]=big[0];` this is *undefined behaviour* because `big` has not been initialised. Even so, you are over-writing `cuv[0]` which you only just made an input in the line above.

Comment: Where in your code do you get the **length** of the strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution. Try to understand the code. Note the code uses  some of the functions from `#include<string.h>`. So, before going through the code please go through `string.h` header file and understand the standard functions it provides.

Anyways, here is a very basic program,(feel free to modify it to your needs)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 256

int main(){

      char input[MAX],*tmp=NULL;
      char *word_list[MAX],*word=NULL;
      int flag[MAX];
      int i=0,index=0,m=0,largest_len=0;

      //Get Input From User
      printf("Enter Input:\n");
      fgets(input,MAX,stdin);

      //If using fgets then use strchr() to locate '\n' and replace it with '\0'(null terminating char)
     if((tmp=strchr(input,'\n')) != NULL){
        *tmp='\0';
      }

      //Use strtok() function to split the sentence/input into words separated by space
     //and store them in an array of char pointers(or more like array of strings)
     word = strtok(input," ");
     word_list[index] = word;
     index++;
     while(word != NULL && i<MAX){
         word=strtok(NULL," "); 
         if(word != NULL){
            word_list[index] = word;
            index++;
         }  
     }

     //find the word with the largest lenght
     for(i=0;i<index;i++){
        if(strlen(word_list[i]) >= largest_len){
           largest_len = strlen(word_list[i]);
        }
     }

     //Then store the index of words which have their lenght equal to the largest lenght
    for(i=0;i<index;i++){
       if(strlen(word_list[i]) == largest_len){
          flag[m] = i;
          m++;
       }
     }

     //Print the largest words
     m=0;
     printf("Largest Word('s):");
     for(i=0;i<index;i++){
        if(flag[m] == i){
           printf("%s ",word_list[i]);
           m++;
        }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you've posted doesn't seem to even come close to what you're trying to do -- so much so that it's really not salvageable towards a solution.

That said, think about your "large" (complete) problem as a series of smaller problems instead; each smaller problem is easier to solve than the single larger problem. Your problems seem to be:

1) Input your raw data.

2) Split your raw data into words. You could manually walk through your data looking for spaces and doing what you feel appropriate when you find them, or you could figure out how to use `strtok()` to parse data for you. Given where you are with your language understanding, doing it manually is probably a better learning experience.

3) Determine the length of the largest word in your collection.

4) Go through your entire collection and output each word whose length is equal to that largest length.

---

For problem 1, you seem to have this accomplished (but pay attention to the suggestions people have given you about better ways to do it).

---

Problem 2 might be the most challenging. There are several ways one can go about it. I'm not going to provide a solution, but this snippet is a small start:

```
for (i = 0; cuv[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Pay attention to the middle term of the for loop; it's not making an assignment to `cuv[i]` (I point this out because in your posted program, you are making an assignment, which is really not what you intend.) It is comparing the character to the standard C string termination.

You'll need to look at each character as you go through the loop and decide if you are increasing the current word, ending the previous word, starting a new word, or just skipping repetitive whitespace.

You'll need to store a pointer to each word somewhere so that the full set of words will be available to steps 3 and 4.

Note that you *could* perform step 3 while you're doing this but you should not for now. It would make your program more efficient, but it merges the steps together and while learning, you don't need that.

---

Problem 3 requires you to be aware that `strlen(const char *s)` will return the length of `s`, where `s` is a properly terminated C string.

To solve this you will simply iterate through your full set of words and inspect the length of each; if the length is greater than the previous maximum you will increase your stored maximum. Something like:

```
unsigned int maxLength = 0;
for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; ++i) {
    if (strlen(word[i]) > maxLength)
        maxLength = strlen(word[i]);
}
```

---

Finally, for step 4 you will iterate through your list of words again, deciding which ones to print out. Something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; ++i) {
    if (strlen(word[i]) == maxLength)
        printf("%s\n", word[i]);
}
```

Comment: You skipped a step: Determine the length of a word -- he doesn't seem to know how to do that basic operation.